# numpy issue with anaconda and pycharm

Tags: numpy, pycharm, anaconda

I have installed pycharm , anaconda and python and trying to import numpy.I have changed the interpeter(system interpeter path to anaconda3/python.exe) path and have succesfully installed numpy (at least according to pycharm)  and use the "import numpy as np" code to import it but for some reason numpy doesnt seem to work. When I try to create a 2d array , I get an error about how a list must be indices or slices and not tuple.I am pretty sure this means that numpy isn't actually imported. I would appreciate if you guys tell me what I am doing wrong because this is really frustrating me.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: NumPy is imported, the error is probably related to the way you try to create a NumPy array

Comment: Please attach the source code